# dns resolving fails in php-fpm chroot using docker

Tags: docker, php-fpm, chroot

Using Docker, I am trying to set up `nginx` + `nextcloud:fpm` in a chroot environment.

It's all set up and working so far except that the software reports that it cannot connect to the internet, the exception states `Could not resolve host: www.github.com`. Providing IP adresses results in timeouts.

Running curl on the docker container runs just fine: `docker exec nextcloud curl www.github.com` and when I used php in interactive mode in bash, it also worked. Also, when I removed the chroot and fixed the paths in nginx it worked.

So it must be about the php-fpm config, but I can't find what it is.

This is my config for php:

www.conf

```
[www]
user = www-data
group = www-data
listen = 9000
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
chroot = /var/www/html
```

I have the following volumes mounted in docker to make chroot work: (they are not accessible from nginx)

```
  - '/dev/urandom:/var/www/html/dev/urandom'
  - '/dev/null:/var/www/html/dev/null'
  - '/dev/zero:/var/www/html/dev/zero'
  - '/etc/timezone:/var/www/html/etc/timezone'
  - '/etc/resolv.conf:/var/www/html/etc/resolv.conf'
  - '/etc/hosts:/var/www/html/etc/hosts'
  - '/etc/host.conf:/var/www/html/etc/host.conf'
  - '/etc/nsswitch.conf:/var/www/html/etc/nsswitch.conf'
  - '/etc/localtime:/var/www/html/etc/localtime'
  - '/usr/share/zoneinfo:/var/www/html/usr/share/zoneinfo'
```

I would like to know what is missing for my php to resolve hostnames.